# AWS CodePipeline deploy Spring Boot application to Elastic BeansTalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I built a simple CodePipeline for a SpringBoot Java application with 3 steps:

- Source: get the source from GitHub
- Build: a jar file
- Deploy: to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance

1 and 2 steps successfully pass while Deploy step fails. The only error I see in Elastic Beanstalk logs:

```
01_configure_application.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: Executing: /usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  FileMagic v0.7.1: compiled magic version [5.21] does not match with shared library magic version [5.37]
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
    inflating: /var/app/staging/microservices/my-service/target/my-service.jar  
  Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile.
  Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Executing: /usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  FileMagic v0.7.1: compiled magic version [5.21] does not match with shared library magic version [5.37]
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
    inflating: /var/app/staging/microservices/my-service/target/my-service.jar  
  Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile.
  Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

My Buildspec:

```
build:
  commands:
      - mvn -P ci --settings settings.xml install -DskipTests
artifacts:
  files:
     - microservices/my-service/target/my-service.jar
```

If I deploy this jar directly to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using AWS Web Interface, it works perfectly.

Please, help me.
I'm ready to share any other config on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in artifact's sub-folders, it's impossible to use an artifact location as in my Buildspec:

```
artifacts:
  files:
     - microservices/my-service/target/my-service.jar
```

the only correct way is `folder/myapp.jar`, for example:

```
artifacts:
  files:
     - target/my-service.jar
```

so you should specify `outputDirectory` in your maven config if it is different

Answer (score 8):

while Denys answer is correct i dont think it clearly explains the issue.

the artifact **must be top level or at most one directory in depth** when it is output under the `artifacts` directive.

for example the default for a spring project using gradle is to output to `<project root>/build/libs/<artifact name>.jar` after executing the `bootJar` task

intuitively you would define something like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  build:
    commands:
      # bootJar task outputs to build/libs/<name>.jar
      - ./gradlew bootJar
artifacts:
  files:
      - build/libs/<name>.jar
```

this build will succeed and upload a zipped artifact to S3. when that is unzipped you will get:

`build/libs/<name>.jar`. you can confirm this by downloading the artifact from s3 and unzipping it yourself (just as elastic beanstalk does within the vm).

so when elastic beanstalk tries to deploy this it fails because it looks either for a top level `<name>.jar` or **at most** `somedir/<name>.jar` and you get that rather cryptic error message

> Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain either a file named application.jar or a Procfile.

its cryptic because it implies that the artifact must either be named `application.jar` or a Procfile must be added. neither of these are true

so the solution revolves around making that jar file top level. you can:

define your output artifact from your build tool as placing it top level (not ideal)

add a second command to the `build` phase that moves that jar file out to the top level such as:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  build:
    commands:
      # bootJar task outputs to build/libs/<name>.jar
      - ./gradlew bootJar
      # move the jar (by wildcard, agnostic to its name) to top level app.jar
      - mv build/libs/*.jar app.jar
artifacts:
  files:
      # publish the now top level app.jar as the artifact
      - app.jar
```

the most appropriate solution is to make use of the `post_build` directive which is designed for cleanup / reorganizing steps like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  build:
    commands:
      # bootJar task outputs to build/libs/<name>.jar
      - ./gradlew bootJar
  post_build:
    commands:
      # move the jar (by wildcard, agnostic to its name) to top level app.jar
      - mv build/libs/*.jar app.jar
artifacts:
  files:
      # publish the now top level app.jar as the artifact
      - app.jar
```

as a result when unzipped you will get `app.jar` top level and elastic beanstalk is happy! note that `app.jar` and `build/libs` are arbitrary, set them however makes sense to you and your project. all that matters is that the `artifacts.files` is a top level jar file. elastic beanstalk will take care of the rest

if you are new to CP or have a simple project there is no need to override with a `config.yml` or add a `Procfile` as suggested in other similar questions.

hope this helps someone else.

Comment: amazing answer, helped me a lot, thanks!